# HTTP Header Field Warning Usage

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

We are in the process of developing an HTTP REST API. One consideration that we're debating is whether to put validation warnings in the header with warning code of 199 (as defined here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

We haven't seen a lot of guidance on whether it would be best to have warnings here. We can potentially have dozens (or more) warnings if lots of warnings occur, primarily validation warnings/errors for a large resource.

The current consideration is between having warnings in the response header versus having warnings in the response body. Alternately, having a single warning with code of 199 indicating that the body contains warning/failure details.

(In any case we would be using an appropriate HTTP status code in the response.)

Comment: You ought to read <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7234.html#header.warning>, RFC 2616 is obsolete.

That being said: Warning is part of HTTP Caching, so I don't see how it's applicable here. Just put the diagnostics into the response body.

Comment: The 1xx codes must only be generated by a cache when validating a cached entry. You might want 2xx (299) instead. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-5.5

Answer (score 3):

It's noteworthy that [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.5) which obsoleted RFC 2616 mentions that:

> Warnings can be used for other purposes, both cache-related and
> otherwise.

Leveraging the HTTP Warning headers collection as a repository for these validation warning messages seems reasonable as long as the 3-digit warning code 199 - "Miscellaneous Warning" is used.